# Docs JSF integrated with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf, tomcat, javadoc

I am using Eclipse Mars and my application server is Tomcat. I have an .xhtml opened with Web Page Editor

When ever I hover over a tag,e.g. f:selectItem, I just see:

```
Element : f:selectItem
```

I'd like to see the documentation about the tag, e.g:

The SelectItem tag adds a child UISelectItem component to the component associated with the enclosing tag. In the HTML renderkit, this creates a single element. It can be used with any of the select tags in the JSF HTML tag library. The body content of this tag must be empty.

[JSF SelectItem Docs](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_selectItem.html)

Is there any new way I can configure the eclipse to do show the javadocs in tag description?

Comment: That link doesn't point to official JSF documentation. It just points to a 3rd party blog/tutorial site which uses its own words. The official JSF (2.2) tag documentation is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/

Comment: Ok.
Is there anyway to show this documentation in tag on Eclipse, when I am developing a xhtml page?